# Way to avoid creating a sub-directory in topicref

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a very simple template match in my xslt code to create a ditamap, and it works by just creating a topicref whenever matches a "Section" of the original document.

The initial xml code fragment looks like:

```
<Section Target="IL27TRM409TueAug251754042009251">
<Heading Target="v5170372">WBG (S-GW/P-GW) chassis </Heading>
```

The xslt template match for section looks like:

```
<xsl:template match="Section> 
 <xsl:variable name="file" select="Heading"/>
 <xsl:variable name="fileName" select="translate(normalize-space($file),' ','_')"/>   
  <topicref format="dita" href="{translate(./$fileName,' ','_')}.xml"  navtitle="{./Heading}">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </topicref>
```

The code works, except that for the Heading like above "WBG (S-GW/P-GW) chassis", it will take the "/" as a sub-folder, so it will create a subforlder called "WBG (S-GW" then create a file "P-GW)_chassis.xml".

Is there a way to make xslt ignore the "/" in the Heading and just treat it as a string to create an xml file by simply using that string?

Comment: XSLT does not create subforlders, it just take any number of XML trees as input and output one (or many in XSLT 2.0) XML tree as output. It might or might not be responsible of serialization. Here, the consumer of your output understand that your `@href` refers to a subfolder. **Why don't you just replace `/` character for other one valid in URIs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert, just to expand on @Alejandro's correct answer/comment:

It's not XSLT that's creating a folder. XSLT is already "ignoring" the `/` in the Heading: it does not treat it as anything special. (Look at XSLT's output and you can see that.)

What OS (or more properly, file system) are you creating files in? Depending on that, '/' may be an illegal character in filenames, so substituting another character for it may be your only option. Try naming a file `a/b` manually and see if it's even possible. Since you are using `normalize-space()` already, it seems that you are not absolutely required to preserve the Heading content precisely in the filename.

To substitute `-` for `/`, modify your `translate()` expression like this:

```
translate(normalize-space($file),' /','_-')
```

This means "substitute `_` for every space, and substitute `-` for every `/`."